# Gitlab with separate Nginx HTTPS SSL not working

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, gitlab

I have a CentOS 7 server (home file server) and I was trying to setup Gitlab with my own Nginx install (so I can use it for other things as well). Nginx version is 1.10.1.

When I use the recommended Nginx conf file without HTTPS, it works. But the HTTPS version does not (even though I have created a self-signed cert and pointed to that). With HTTPS, Chrome just says "This site can't be reached".

I can create another site in Nginx that uses a different name and it works with HTTPS, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

The working settings are:

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket;
}

## Normal HTTP host
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name git.REDACTED; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.com
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  ## See app/controllers/application_controller.rb for headers set

  ## Individual nginx logs for this GitLab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }
}
```

And the HTTPS settings that don't work:

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket fail_timeout=0;
}

## Redirects all HTTP traffic to the HTTPS host
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name git.mattval.dynu.com; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.com
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  return 301 https://$http_host:443$request_uri;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;
}

## HTTPS host
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name git.REDACTED; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.com
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  ## Strong SSL Security
  ## https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html & https://cipherli.st/
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/gitlab.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/gitlab.key;

  # GitLab needs backwards compatible ciphers to retain compatibility with Java IDEs
  ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  ## See app/controllers/application_controller.rb for headers set

  ## Individual nginx logs for this GitLab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this just turned out to be my mistake. I was using a domain setup with a dynamic DNS site, so it pointed to my server's external address. But my firewall was only allowing web traffic from my local 192.168.1.x subnet. Even though I was accessing this from my local network, it was going over the WAN and getting blocked by the firewall. I allowed access with the firewall and it is working now.